# Single word meaning "pregnant woman"

Tags: single-word-requests

Does such a word exist?

It has occurred to me that the "woman" part is redundant, since only women can be pregnant (except for Arnold Schwarzanegger in [Junior](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110216/))

Comment: *"only women can be pregnant"* — Well, so can cows, cats, and so on.

Comment: Sex-wise, actually. Gender's a bit more fluid.

Comment: True. "Gender-wise" only women can be pregnant. Although In most circumstances it would come up, the species is implied

Comment: I'd rather say *pregnant woman* is the "norm".  But I don't think it's "redundant" as one might want to use **woman** as opposed to **child** or **teenager**. One usually says a *pregnant child* or a *pregnant teenager*, without specifying the gender.

Comment: @Laure barring rare medical conditions, I don't think one usually says *pregnant child*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard more due to people abiding by the law and social norms, than medical conditions. A newspaper would refer to a pregnant 11 year old as a "pregnant child" -- or even an older girl, for impact. http://abcnews.go.com/Health/pregnant-children-face-risk-death-labor-developing-world/story?id=15163624#.Tut48jVmIug . The point Laure is making though, is that "child" and "teenager" are gender-neutral, yet are the words we would choose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Primagravida* is a medical term for somebody pregnant for the first time, and *multigravida* is in the OED for somebody pregnant not for the first time, so you could coin *gravida*, I suppose.  But in normal usage, I'd say there is no such noun.

Comment: The noun **gravida** for a "pregnant female" is mentioned in (Wikipedia)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregnancy], in the online edition of the                       [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gravida), in the                                                (Free Dictionary)[http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gravida] and in the paper editions of *Webster's third International Dictionary* and in *Longman's Dictionary of the English Language*. I did not find it in the *OED* or in the *BBC English Dictionary*.

Comment: "gravida" is a medical term for a pregnant woman. "gravid" is an adjective meaning "pregnant". (I don't know why doctors need another word to mean pregnant, but whatever.) Both words would be recognized by doctors, but probably pretty much no one else. What's wrong with simply saying "pregnant woman"?

Comment: @Jay I don’t think *gravid* for *pregnant* is so rare as to be unrecognized outside of medicine.

Comment: @tchrist I've never seen it used by other than doctors and nurses in a medical context, but of course I can't speak to professions or social circles other than my own, etc.

Comment: (Tradition and professional pride probably dictate using *gravid* rather than pregnant. But as it can be a sensitive topic, using "gravid" about a patient would probably go unnoticed in a hospital whereas "pregnant" might raise unwelcome curiosity among other visitors or patients.)

Answer (score 8):

If you can accept a hyphenated phrase, then ***mum-to-be*** or ***mother-to-be*** are quite common.

(Or ***mom-to-be*** in the USA, I presume?)

Comment: I've also heard people use "the expecting", but I think it's a rather obnoxious-sounding term.

Comment: In the US it would be "mother-to-be".

Comment: That would also include women who are about to adopt a child, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 8):

Extremely informally, people may say a "preggo"

Comment: I think it is more than extremely informal; a search on Yahoo Answers of "preggo" shows it was used in 21700 questions

Comment: +1 for a nice word. Wish it was in more common use.

Comment: Ye gods, but I hate that "word".

Comment: Around here, that's more than informal, it's offensive.  Less offensive as an adjective however.  Consider http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preggo.

Answer (score 6):

The OED records *pregnant* as a noun as well as an adjective, with the meaning ‘a pregnant woman’, with three citations from the twentieth century alone. I wouldn’t say it was in common use though.

Comment: Really? It makes sense, but it just sounds so very wrong: "Please avoid heavy lifting if you are _a pregnant_."

Comment: @Urbycoz: The twentieth century citations show the usage in medical contexts. As I said, not, in my experience, common.

Comment: I wouldn't think twice about a sentence like *The pregnant should take care not to use certain medications*.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: that's more like a mass noun than in Urbycoz's "Please avoid heavy lifting if you are a pregnant." Where idiomatic use would drop the *a*.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: That sounds like a plural. How about 'A pregnant . . .'?

Comment: True, true. A mass noun indeed.

Comment: It wouldn't be used in the singular, I'm quite confident. If you were to use the definite article (the only non-barbaric usage I can think of), it would be a collective noun: *The pregnant are a society unto themselves.* You would not (no, never) say *A pregnant is well advised to lay off alcohol and tobacco.*

Comment: @Robusto 初夢: The most recent OED citation illustrates its use as a countable noun (but not a singular one): 'For adults, they have three boxes or categories in which a doctor may put a cross: men, women, pregnants.'

Comment: @Barrie: OK, but that sounds awful too.

Comment: @Robusto初夢: Possibly, but sounding awful is not a valid linguistic judgement.

Comment: @Barrie: Which is why I made the comment here, not on Linguistics.SE. English is not a science, and sounding awful is a valid usage note.

Comment: Re "the pregnant should...": whatever the part of speech, it's a transformation that could be applied to almost any adjective: "the drowsy should avoid driving cars"; "the successful have a tendency to be arrogant"; "give me your tired, your poor, ...".

Comment: @phoog:   Precisely.  "The <adjective>...." for "<adjective> people" is an idiom which applies to all adjectives (that can be applied to people) and that usage doesn't constitute any kind of evidence that "pregnant" can be used as a noun.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: No, but my citation does.

Answer (score 2):

The real frain is whether such a word is needed.

OE had byrþestre (e) f. *female carrier*. So I guess a modern version could be: **birthster**.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever heard anybody use it in conversation, but [venter](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=venter+meaning&pbx=1&oq=venter+meaning&aq=f&aqi=g-s4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=12144l14830l1l15619l8l8l0l0l0l1l1022l4612l3-3.1.2.1.1l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b4abb1b296fb37aa&biw=1280&bih=687) means a pregnant woman.

**EDIT:** In response to the comment by jwpat and the upvoters: [Here is a link](http://msowww.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/v003/wb1913_v.html), and here is [another.](http://thinkexist.com/dictionary/meaning/venter/)(In the first link, do a *Ctrl+F* and look up definition 6)

Comment: Among links from your link, none of [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/venter#Noun_2), [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/venter), or [medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/venter) support that usage.  The last refers to "the abdomen, the uterus"; the second gives "in venter, Law, conceived but not yet born"; and the first gives the close-but-not-quite "A woman with offspring".  Can you point to a specific reference instead of an inconclusive search page, and incorporate part of the result into your answer?

Comment: @jwpat: done. Here's another link: http://www.webster-dictionary.net/definition/Venter

Answer (score -2):

A bold use of the word *Alpha-bitch* or even *Queen* might suffice.

Mums-to-be could also be known as *'Ovens'* or *'Hosts'* (depending on whether the baby is referred to as a bun or a parasite).

Comment: This answer might be improved by pointing out that these choices are likely to be found offensive.