# If trinity means 3 in one, what's the word for one in one, 2 in one, 4 in one, 5 in one?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

In Christianity, there is the doctrine of the "trinity" of God. What would be the name of the corresponding doctrine if the number three were replaced with two, four or five?

Comment: Well, all I know is the word for six in one is *sixpack*.  ;-)

Comment: BTW: We wouldn't say "3 monotheistic Gods make up the Trinity". The whole point of the idea of the Trinity is that there is only one monotheistic God -- hence the "mono" part -- but he is made up of 3 persons. That is, we say "3 persons of God make up the Trinity".

Comment: I was joking. In logic, if you can proof an absurdity you can proof anything. In practice, if you can make someone believe an absurdity, you can make them do anything. +1 for all the witty comments.

Comment: -1 Vote to close as not constructive. If you want to joke about other people's religion, find another forum.

Comment: Hei, it's a serious question. Till now I do not know why we have a trinity. I mean why not quadrinity or binity or pentanity or hexity. What language does the number come from? Sanskrit?

Comment: What I mean I was joking is that no body really knows what trinity means. There are several different interpretation, each of which is considered heretical to another. Heretical enough to justify bloodshed that's one thing for sure. So I just said three monotheistic God. After all, it's three, yet monotheistic.

Comment: It's a shame this question was closed, as it was the very thing I was looking for. It's not, I think, a religious question at its base. I did find a suggestion elsewhere that the answer would be: "Duality, Triality, Quadrality, Pentality, Hexality, Heptality, Octality, Ninality". I think these are math terms, though, e.g., "triality" not "trinity". There's also "triad" which I'm not sure has an equivalent in 4, 5, 6, etc.

(This would also be a legitimate question for a fiction author, especially sci-fi, who wanted to write about a race that believed in a "pentality"...)

Comment: @JimThio, Seriously? What has this English question even got to do with religion (unless you're primed to think that way)? **So all words used by religion become automatically off-limits?** That's thousands upon thousands of words barred.

Comment: Trinity:  a group of three people or things.
"the wine was the first of a trinity of three excellent vintages".  Are we supposed  to believe the "tri" is a coincidence?

Comment: The point of "too localized," as I understand it, is that a question so characterized is of little interest to anyone but the poster. But in this case, 33,204 people have viewed this page—despite its having been closed three days after it was asked—so perhaps it's time to rethink the assertion that the question is of little interest to anyone but the poster.

Comment: My head hurts. I read every world. Wow, are you guys ever INTELLIGENT. I was just looking for "Quadrinity" and found it, and then some. My brain feels full.

Comment: There are some who prefer the word 'Triunity' to better express the oneness as well as the threeness (though man's on a loser with Theology [proper]; a God one can fully understand isn't a God). Although 'Triunity' is a specialist term, so this is really off-topic. For once, I'll abuse the ELU platform. Some things are that important.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, owing to various heresies and schisms in the Christian faith we presently have the following forms of monotheistic doctrine:

*Unity* - Espoused by the Unitarians, who reject the consubstantiation of God and hold that He is strictly a single person. Jesus is regarded by Unitarians as a prophet who is not a part of the godhead.

*Binity* - Advocated by the Binitarians, who believe in the co-divinity of Jesus the Son and God the Father. What I find particularly interesting about them is that they believe Jesus was fully divine and co-eternal prior to becoming human, but that he fully surrendered his divinity while in human form, only to regain it in resurrection. This differs from the standard mainstream trinitarian view that Jesus the man was both divine and human.

So to make it really confusing, the Binitarians treat Jesus as a unity at all times, while the trinitarians see his human form as a binity.  Still with me?  :D

*Trinity* - The orthodox mainline Christian theology of the coexistent, coeternal three in one: Father, Son and Holy Ghost.

I am not aware of any further such terms of particular Christian significance, but there's a seemingly Scientology-like thing called the Hoffman Quadrinity Process that is all over the Internet and apparently in several countries.

If the Pope ever did pronounce the five-fold nature of God, I expect the word would continue to be based on the Latin root -nitas, and so following the pattern it would be *quintinity*.

Me, I'm signing up as an infinitarian. If the godhead has constituent parts, it's some unquantifiable number in one. An infinity.

Comment: +1. THis is an even better answer.

Comment: I don't think *binity* has much currency in religious or any other context. Far more common are *dualism, duotheism, bitheism,* and *ditheism*.

Comment: In popular religious discourse it's exceedingly rare, but it's common currency in formal theology. It's of particular relevance in scholarship of the early pre-Nicene Christian church. Many of the early Christian apologists are seen as binitarian monotheists, which is in no way the same thing as ditheism. But it has not been uncommon for those who disagree with the binitarian view to label it dismissively as a ditheistic heresy. So, um...when can we have theologynuts.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Or maybe *quinity*?

Comment: +1 for *quintinity*. The OP is not so much about religion as it is about language. Just *quintinity* should have sufficed, I suppose.

Comment: Yea why quintinity? Why not pentainity? Why quadrinity? Why not quadrality? Why use quint? Why not penta? What language is mono bi tri quad quint anyway? Latin? Greek?

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I think *dualism* is a different belief altogether. It's about two opposing forces, as in Zoroastrianism.

Comment: @TRiG: Dualism has [various meanings](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=dualism&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=Hu6ZT6DzJ8i-8APtyqGwBg&ved=0CCYQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c5d78a5637935dd9&biw=1237&bih=902) - sense 3 there applies to religion in general, and sense 4 to the Christian concept of Christ being both human and divine. Anyway, I just meant that *binity* has negligible currency in *any* context, compared particularly to *dualism*, but even to the other three alternatives I gave.

Answer (score 12):

*Duality* is 2 in 1,
*Trinity* is 3 in 1,
*Quadrality* is 4 in 1

That's as far as I know them.

*Primality* should work for 1 in 1, at least from the mathematical point of view.

Comment: Or _unity_. That's what the Unitarian Church is about.

Comment: Can _duality_ actually be used that way? In my experience, _duality_ can only mean "a quality of something that is 2 things in one", not the 2 things in one itself; thus, we can say that "Jekyll and Hyde exhibit a duality of personality," but we can't say "Jekyll and Hyde ARE a duality." I think _trinity_ is the only such word that can refer to the "_n_ in one" thing itself. Having said that, though, if the Pope decided that there was a Holy Duality instead of trinity, and this became official doctrine, I'm sure the new usage would catch on :)

Comment: @alcas: Interesting point, but then we're always shifting parts of speech. Like, "hungry" is an adjective, yet if you say "The hungry of the world ..." people know what you mean.

Comment: I agree that duality/quadrality/primality are not part of this family. But Gnawme's suggestion of *unity* is correct - it's theologically significant and from the same root as trinity: unitas, trinitas.

Comment: @Jay:  This just came up over here [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51908/single-word-meaning-pregnant-woman] -- see my comment:  "The <adjective>...." for "<adjective> people" is an idiom which applies to all adjectives (that can be applied to people) and that usage doesn't constitute any kind of evidence that <adjective> has shifted to be a noun.

Comment: Why quadrality? Why not quadrity? or pentaity?

Comment: This is the best answer because it relates to the actual question not the example causing all the religious white-noise debate. The Op found a word that depicts a mathematical series and I am also interested in words following up on that series. So the question is why not "monity", "binity" or "dunity"? Where does ["tri"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_prefix) and "-nity" come from?

Comment: Quaternity is the word for 4 in 1.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that this is not an entirely serious question, so here's a not entirely serious answer. A quadripartite deity would be a *tetrakism* and a quintipartite one  would be a *pentalogy*.

Comment: I think by the time we get to someone claiming their god embodies five or more aspects, *polytheist* probably makes more sense (if indeed any of it ever could).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Non-Christians might make the same case against the trinity.

Comment: Atheists might make a similar case against any number of "godheads" greater than zero. But I seem to recall there are [primitive?] languages that don't really have words for any numbers greater than three - the missionaries of this hypothetical "five-way godhead" might find they've got their work cut out there!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Indeed. They'd just have to make do with 'many'.

Comment: I *knew* I was right! Last paragraph [here](https://lsadc.org/info/meet-annual11-media.cfm) starts with *Australian languages tend to have restricted numeral systems, stereotypically* **"one, two, three, many."** I'm sure I've come across that as a "4-word stereotype" for certain languages before.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If you want to find a linguistic oddity, there's a safe bet you'll find it in one Australian language or another!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There's a very distinct difference between polytheism and Trinitarianism: polytheism says many gods, Trinitarianism says one God with multiple aspects. Increasing the number of aspects doesn't turn him into multiple gods. That would be like saying that now that XYZ Corporation has four subsidiaries, it is no longer a single tax entity; or now that you have four children, you are no longer a single family. It may seem a subtle distinction if you're an "outsider" who doesn't believe any of it, but believe me, the implications are huge. :-)

Comment: @Jay: It's true I am an "outsider", so I must be careful not to tread too heavily on other people's beliefs. Perhaps I should have said *pantheist* rather than *polytheist* - according to my understanding that nets down to the belief that *everything* is an aspect of the godhead. But it does often seem that's the position of some Christians anyway - Christianity is a broad church, as they say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, I'm sure a theological discussion would be off-track here. There might be people who call themselves Christians who believe in pantheism, but this is pretty clearly not a part of traditional or orthodox Christianity. (I'm sure there are people who call themselves Democrats who disagree with 90% of the Democrat party platform, etc.) There's a huge difference between "God has many aspects" and "everything is an aspect of God". Like the difference between "McDonalds has restaurants everywhere" and "every restaurant is a McDonalds".

Comment: Trinity is not simply one God with three aspects. Such believe is called nestorianism or something. In fact, in Christianity, it once was a heresy condemnable to eternal damnation. Let's just hope, for humanity's sake, everyone can count all the way to 3. Let's hope God don't create another aspect after that.

Answer (score 2):

## Quaternity

[@RiMMER](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6509) said that "Quadrality" would be a term, however, [according to *Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quaternity), the following is the proper term:

> Definition of ***quaternity***: a union of a group or set of four

[Quadrality does not seem to be used](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadrality).

Comment: And [Collins defines "quaternity"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/quaternity) as "a group of four, esp a concept of God as consisting of four persons". I wouldn't rule out "quadrality" just because it's not in Merriam-Webster though. There are a couple uses of the word "quadrality" for the idea that God has four persons.