# If a Trinity means 3 in 1, what is 3 in 2, 3 in 3, 3 in N?

Tags: terminology, suffixes

Piggybacking off [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52014/if-trinity-means-3-in-one-whats-the-word-for-one-in-one-2-in-one-4-in-one-5) about words which define an N-in-one entity, I wanted to ask a question about the case for the suffix.

A Trinity is 3-in-1, but what word(s) describe a 3-in-2 entity, a 3-in-3 entity, a 3-in-N entity?

Comment: Leaving aside theology for a moment, I kind of understand what an *N-in-1* thing might be, kind of like a multi-tool.  But using the same kind of analogy, what would an example of an *N-in-2* think be ?  And it had better not be an *N/2-in-1* thing plus another *N/2-in-1* thing !  Getting a bit more on-topic, the concepts are extremely difficult to grasp, I don't think you'll find any words more apposite than the constructions you already have.

Comment: Apart from golf ("a hole in 2"), I can't think of any usage of the term "3-in-2" that would make sense, so I'm not sure what sort of term you're looking for here. Can you describe what "3-in-2" means? Also, _entity_ is a term that relates to "-in-1" because it is referring to the "1". A suffix of "-in-2" would no longer be an _entity_.

Comment: @Ian MacDonald Trinity --> "An entity where 3 is one and one is three"
<3 - in - 2 word> --> "An entity where 3 is two and two is three"

Comment: "An entity where apples are sharks and sharks are apples". Repeating yourself does not give an example. As far as I can tell, "3-in-2" is nonsense. Please describe what you want this to mean.

Comment: The Triunity is unique; how can the human mind grasp the nature of the Godhead fully? Why should say 'bi-quaternity' be meaningful?

Comment: Man has invented the "trinity", yet has not invented "word(s) [that] describe a 3-in-2 entity, a 3-in-3 entity, a 3-in-N entity" as there has been none need. There are no such words.

Comment: "Trinity" means "three".  The 3-in-1 concept is a religious thing.

Comment: And, yes,  "3-in-2" is nonsense.  It's a meaningless concept.

Comment: Basic: how's 3-in-n an "entity"? Can you demonstrate that it is so?

Comment: See also [math.se]. Good Luck.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark would an N - in - 2 entity could be a siamese twin organism that is a chimera with N genotypes qualify: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(genetics)?

Answer (score 3):

While it's difficult, if not impossible, to prove a negative, I feel fairly confident saying, as High Performance Mark and Greybeard have, that:

> **No such words exist**

And, since this is an English Language & ***Usage*** site, I'll add that I feel even more comfortable adding that there are no such words that are common enough that greater than 1% of English speakers would know them.

Comment: Note that others have already said this. If you feel that the site recommendations are that such probably unprovable but very probably correct claims should be made in 'answers', note also that the site recommendations are that answers with repeats of such claims already made in 'comments' by those who feel that unprovable claims should be confined to comments, should acknowledge the piggybackees.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So noted